# How can you sort string value or array in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hello Stackoverflow SQL experts,

**What I am looking for:**
A way to sort string of text in Snowflake SQL.

**Example:**
My table looks like something like this:

```
---------------------
| ID   | REFS       |
---------------------
| ID1  | 'ANN,BOB'  |
| ID2  | 'BOB,ANN'  |
---------------------
```

As you can see my ID1 and ID2 are referred by both Ann and Bob.
But because they were inputted in different orders, they aren't recognized as a group.
Is there a way to sort the String/list values in REF? to clean up REFs?
so when I do counts and group bys. it would be

```
--------------------------
| REFS       | COUNT(ID) |
--------------------------
| 'ANN,BOB'  | 2         |
--------------------------
```

Instead of....

```
--------------------------
| REFS       | COUNT(ID) |
--------------------------
| 'ANN,BOB'  | 1         |
| 'BOB,ANN'  | 1         |
--------------------------
```

**What I have tried:**

- TO_ARRAY(REFS) - But this just creates two lists, ['ANN','BOB'] and ['BOB','ANN']
- SPLIT(REFS,',') - This also just creates

I have other REF lists containing all sorts of combinations.

```
'BOB,CHRIS,ANN'
'BOB,CHRIS'
'CHRIS'
'DAVE,ANN'
'ANN,ERIC'
'FRANK,BOB'
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the data model!  Storing multiple values in a string is a bad idea.  That said, you can split, unnest, and reaggregate.  I think this works in Snowflake:

```
select t.*,
       (select list_agg(s.value, ',') within group (order by s.value)
        from table(split_to_table(t.refs, ',')) s
       ) normalized_refs
from t;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work in Snowflake: `SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH data(id, refs) as (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
        ('ID1', 'ANN,BOB'),
        ('ID2', 'BOB,ANN'),
        ('ID3', 'CHRIS,BOB,ANN')
)
SELECT order_arry, count(distinct(id)) as count 
FROM (

  SELECT array_agg(val) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) over (partition by id) as order_arry, id
  FROM (
    SELECT d.id, trim(s.value) as val
    FROM data d, lateral split_to_table(d.refs, ',') s
  )
)
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```

gives:

```
ORDER_ARRY  COUNT
[    "ANN",    "BOB"  ] 2
[    "ANN",    "BOB",    "CHRIS"  ] 1
```

but as Gordon notes, the partiton by is not needed thus the distinct is also not needed;

```
SELECT ordered_arry, count(id) as count 
FROM (

  SELECT id, array_agg(val) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) as ordered_arry
  FROM (
    SELECT d.id, trim(s.value) as val
    FROM data d, lateral split_to_table(d.refs, ',') s
  )
  GROUP BY 1
)
GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY 1;
```